# Multiple targets in Vapor Xcode project

Tags: swift, heroku, targets, vapor

I'm working with Vapor in Xcode, deploying to Heroku.
My web app is working perfectly. Really pleased with Vapor and how easy it is to deploy to Heroku.

I'm now trying to create a separate Heroku Worker process in the same project. I've added the new worker to my Heroku Procfile, but I am not clear how I should set up the second target in the Xcode project so that it doesn't get overwritten every time I run `vapor xcode` to rebuild the project file.

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=$PORT --config:postgresql.url=$DATABASE_URL
worker: Worker --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=$PORT --config:postgresql.url=$DATABASE_URL
```

So, as you can see, I simply want a second app executable called `Worker` that I can start up within a Heroku worker dyno.

Any idea how I can have a web App target and a separate worker target in my Xcode project that won't get overwritten by `vapor xcode`?

Thanks
--TJ

Answer (score 2):

Ah hah! Solved it. In order to have multiple targets in the project, you need to define them in the Package.swift file for the Swift package manager that is responsible for building the project file.

So, my Package.swift now looks like this:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "myapp",
    targets: [
        Target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Shared"]),
        Target(name: "Worker", dependencies: ["Shared"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
        ]
)
```

My Sources directory structure now looks like this:

`Sources
   |
    - App
    - Worker
    - Shared`

The Shared target contains all of my shared code that is required by the App and the Worker executable targets.

Now, defining the Procfile as above works perfectly. I now have a web app, and a worker process.

Cheers
--TJ

Comment: I'm trying this solution with Vapor 3 / Swift 4.1.2 / XCode 9.4.1 but without any luck. Any suggestions to get this working in latest versions ? One of the errors: "could not find target(s): Worker; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path"  but adding path doesn't seem to fix things. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: we're still stuck in vapour 2.0 for now ... we'll be migrating soon hopefully. sorry I can't help yet.